# AWS Redshift EXISTS Condition Error

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, exists

My schema is just for testing something and table has only 1 row:

```
create table public.simon_test (MaxID bigint);
insert into public.simon_test (MaxID) values (6129498);
```

`transactionsale` has numerous columns but the ones of interest are:

- transactionsaleid bigint PK
- Amount decimal
- storeid bigint

I am trying to run this SQL in Amazon Redshift:

```
select 
  storeid, 
  sum(Amount) as SalesAmount
from transactionsale ts 
where exists (select 1 from simon_test s where s.maxid < ts.transactionsaleid)
group by storeid;
```

I get the error:

> 'Invalid operation: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error;'.

However, this works fine:

```
select
  storeid, 
  sum(saleitemcount) as CntItems,
  sum(Amount) as SalesAmount
from transactionsale ts inner join simon_test s on ts.transactionsaleid > s.MaxID
group by storeid;
```

But I would have thought both should work and wanted to test performance.

What am I missing? It doesn't seem to qualify for any of the [unsupported subquery patterns](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_correlated_subqueries.html).

Comment: I suspect that the query optimizer tries to do a JOIN between the query and subquery, but it can't do that with a "select 1" type of query. I wonder if you can do `WHERE ts.transactionsaleid > (select maxid from from simon_test)` or something similar.

Comment: I think it's just a some problem with your cluster. I've just ran the query, and got result as expected. Contact with support they will provide you the best answer.